# Why responsive email works well on litmus test, but broken after sending it

Tags: android, iphone, css, responsive-design, html-email

I am testing a responsive email template named "Sidebar Hero" provided by ink, here's the [link](http://zurb.com/ink/templates.php).

And when I test it at litmus, the screenshots at android and apple show that responsive works great as expected. Here's my test's screenshots: [android4.0](https://litmus.com/pub/e4b5b1d/results#android4-full_on), and [iPhone](https://litmus.com/pub/e4b5b1d/results#android4-full_on). You can check others android and iPhone aside.

But when I sent it from client(like thunderbird, outlook), the responsive broken. The email looks like a mess. Here's the scrrenshot:
[image: Test responsive email at iPhone and samsung]

How code was produced:
I download the [template code](http://zurb.com/ink/downloads/templates/sidebar-hero.html.zip) directly from template page, and then use [inliner tool](http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php) provided by Ink too to make style inline. And then nothing. Everything done. In case you need my [code](http://www.bpaste.net/show/MdyqgbQW0lJKIKvsmwHj/)

### What I miss Or Any unaware mistakes that I make?

Anyone can help. Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sending it through a corporate MS Exchange network? Sounds similar to an [issue I had a while ago](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/post/26302/#p26302) where the Exchange server at my work was stripping my media queries. Maybe try sending to a different email address on a different non-corporate domain to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Not all. I sent it through Gmail too and other email server(163 etc). Not luck also. Do you have some can work to let me know and have a try? Thanks :D

Comment: Where are you sending it from?  Are you using an email service provider or are you pasting your code into Outlook?

Comment: John is going in the right direction here. You should be sending it through a proper email service provider. Outlook and thunderbird will totally screw with your media queries (and HTML I've seen links not work). Look into services like MailChimp and Campaign Monitor. They are designed to send HTML emails properly.

Comment: @DarrylVos. Thanks. I will try MailChimp and Campaign Monitor as Darryl suggest. I sent email using thunderbird and outlook. Maybe they did trim my code. :D

Comment: @John, I paste my code into outlook and thunderbird. I will try services like MailChimp and Campaign Monitor suggested by Darryl Vos.

Comment: @DarrylVos, you give me a big help. Campaign Monitor do the right thing !! Thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue...

In the docs it recommends using the [Block grid](http://zurb.com/ink/docs.php#block-grid) for Gmail (Mobile, iOS, Android) because it is still flexible without using media queries. Also check out the compatability table right above the "Sub Grid" header.

Apparently the main caveat for using the block grid instead of the default one is:

"Make sure that there isn't any whitespace between your  elements, otherwise Thunderbird will add a gap between your block-grid elements."

Answer (score 0):

For floating two columns on top of each other ink template it's using column splitting instead of table aligning.

An issue that I found regarding this method is that `display-block` or `float:left` on "`td`" is not working for some android versions because the `Doctype` gets stripped.

The solution is to use "`th`" instead of "`td`" and to make sure to override the `font-weight` and align for "`th`", cause by default it's bold and center.